# problema login php y mysql

Tags: php, mysqli, php7, mysqldb

Hola como puedo hacer que una vez que el usuario haya ingresado los datos,
validarlo en la base de datos Si el usuario no existe, mostrar el mensaje
“Usuario no existe”, y crear un texto linkeable que diga “Volver”, y que lo
diriga hacia la página de “login.php”. Si el usuario existe, crear una sesión con el campo “nombre” del trabajador, y mostrarlo por pantalla junto con una frase de bienvenida. Ejemplo “Bienvenido pedro torres”

este es el código php que realice

```
 <?php

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

 $usuario = $_POST ['usuario'];
 $contraseña = $_POST ['password'];

 $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bdprint");
 $query = "SELECT * FROM trabajador WHERE usuario = '".$usuario."' AND 
 clave =  '".$contraseña."'";
 $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);

 $filas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

 if ($filas>0) {
 header("Location:home.php");
 }
 else 
 {
 header("Location: home.php");
 exit ("Usuario no existe");
}
 }

?>
```

y este el html , bueno el html esta en el mismo archivo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
 <title>Login</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/estilos.css" />
 </head>

<body>

 <h1>Login</h1>

<form action="login.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" />
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" />
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

y el archivo home.php no tengo nada es donde cuando ingrese el usuario y si
esta registrado en la base de dato debería aparecer con una BIENVENIDA.. y si
no debería poner usuario no existe

entonces es donde no tengo el conocimiento suficiente a un , espero que me
puedan ayudar , saludos

Comment: hola, a que te refieres con texto plano ?

Comment: en la base de dato ya creo el usuario :xxx y contraseña :123456 ( de prueba), después solo logueo el usuario que cree, gracias por esa definición, estoy estudiando es mi 1 año ,estoy aprendiendo , se agradece la ayuda